# How does Maul acquire all the extra Kyber Crystals?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels, darth-maul

In the Clone Wars episode “Brothers” (S4 E22), we see Maul given half his lightsaber by Savage Opress. Later, during Maul and Ahsoka’s duel (S7 E10), Maul has gained another lightsaber end for his single lightsaber that remained from Savage.

Additionally, when Maul appears in Rebels “Twilight of the Apprentice” (S2 E21-22), he has gained another blade on his lightsaber that looks like half a normal lightsaber, and half an inquisitorial lightsaber.

So the main question is, where is Maul getting all these lightsaber crystals for his lightsabers?

Comment: If memory serves, the Sith make synthetic kyber crystals, so with access to the right equipment, it'd be possible to make more.

Comment: @HansOlo, You may be right, but I’d like to find some actual info on how he gained the blades versus “he has ‘em, end of story” sort of thing.

Comment: @HansOlo Actually, that is no longer canon. Sith now make red lightsabers by corrupting kyber crystals

Comment: Hmm, then I stand corrected!

Comment: His saber in rebels is just an Inquisitor's one with fidget spinner ring broken not that he needs it